# Printing specific information when a number is inputted

Tags: python, variables

I'm creating a program that allows a person to input a student's data into a database, then allows the data for that specific person to be retrieved when their unique student number is entered.

I'm very much a beginner so I have no idea how to go about this. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

The top line of the code, which for some reason won't copy and paste properly, essentially just asks if you want to enter student details (e) or view student details (v).

```
file = open ("newfile.csv","a")

if choice == "e":
    file.write(input("Enter student number: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student surname: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student forename: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student date of birth: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student home address: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student home phone number: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student gender: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student tutor group: ")+"\n")
    file.write(input("Enter student school email: ")+"\n")
    file.close()


if choice == "v":


    temp = open("newfile.csv")
    file = temp.read()


    eachStudent = file.split("\n")
    print(eachStudent)
```

Comment: Hello! Please, explain in detail your problem. "won't copy and paste properly" is too vague. What happens exactly? Do you get an error? If so, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57803646/edit) your post to add the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open ("newfile.csv","a")

if choice == "e":
    file.write("00\nABCD\n01\nPQRS\n02\nWXYZ\n")
    file.close()


if choice == "v":
    temp = open("newfile.csv")
    file = temp.read()
    eachStudent = file.split("\n")
    studentNumber=input("enter student number")
    start=eachStudent.index(studentNumber)
    end=start+2;    
    print(eachStudent[start:end])
```

Above Code will print detail of particular student detail as a list 
And In your case **end=start+9** 
Need to use strip() when work with user input as a string